# Include header that may or may not exist on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, header, conditional-compilation, winapi

So, I am trying to deal with small differences in the various versions of the Windows SDK but am having trouble determining during compilation precisely what version of the Windows SDK I am building against in C++.

As of version 6.1 of the Windows SDK, there is a WinSDKVer.h file that contains some version information that I could use to determine what version of the SDK is being used even though it does not contain a direct version number for the SDK. However, 6.0A does not include this header file, so simply inserting #include  and then using something like #ifdef will not work since there is no WinSDKVer.h in the environment.

A colleague of mine had a vague recollection of a way to include a header on Windows if and only if it exists, but could not remember any details and I have so far failed to find any information on doing so either on stackoverflow or the internet.

I've already done what I can to our make process to try to force the use of a 6.1 or greater SDK if installed on the developer's machine, but I'm also interested if others have run into this general kind of issue before and if/how they solved it.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(ugly) create your own empty version of the header file and place it on a folder. Then add this folder last in your include directories. if the file exists in the SDK it will be included; otherwise your file will be used.

Comment: Yeah, I think this may be the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do it on C++ level. You can do it on build system level — e.g. in SCons see ["Checking for the Existence of Header Files"](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/x4158.html). The basic idea is to compile a little program that just includes the file, and see whether compilation succeeds or fails. Then you can set a macro that says if you have the header, or not, and do

```
#ifdef HAVE_WINSDKVER_H
#    include <winsdkver.h>
#endif
```

or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Do some spelunking through historic versions of the SDK headers, looking for a header file that has existed in all versions of the SDK but contains subtle variation in its `#defines` in different SDK versions.  You can test these with `#ifdef` to distinguish the SDKs.

Obviously it'll have to be some file other than *WinSDKVer.h*, and in some cases you may need a combination of several files.

I did [something similar for Palm OS SDKs](http://prc-tools.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/prc-tools/prc-tools/include/NewTypes.h) many years ago.

Comment: The drawback to this approach is that if the defines change back and forth, it may eventually fail. Still, I can see it being good enough for the task at hand.

Comment: @Johntonsoup: Not really.  The nature of existing SDKs is that they don't change any more; the nature of future SDKs is that they include _WinSDKVer.h_ -- you just have to get at it without disturbing use of the pre-6.1 SDKs.